# Icicle de Derecha a izquierda

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Quisiera saber como puedo invertir en forma de espejo un icicle tree. Los padres deben ir a la derecha pero no puedo acomodarlos adecuadamente. Este es un código base muy similar al que tengo: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle. Creo que debo cambiar el:

```
.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y0},${d.x0})`);
```

Cree una función llamada

```
function positions(d){
  console.log(d.depth)
  if (d.depth == 0){
      d = d.children[0].children[0].children[0];
      return (d.x0);
  }
  else if(d.depth == 1){
      d = d.children[0];
      return (d.x0);
  }
  else if(d.depth == 2){
      d = d.parent;
      return (d.x0);
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Pero creo que eso no es como debo cambiarlo... Existe alguna forma de hacer un *flip* al view box?

```
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya logré solucionar el problema. El código que utilicé fue `.attr("transform", d => translate(${mirror(d.target)},${d.target.x0}))`

Con una función llamada

```
function mirror(d) {
  return width - ((d.depth + 1) * (d.y1 - d.y0));
}
```

Y para el evento de click se añade

```
depth: d.depth - p.depth,
```